# Setting multiple GDAL environment variables when installing multiple versions

Tags: python, gdal, installation

I have set up GDAL v1.1.1 32bit to work with Python 2.7.18 32bit on windows 10 and everything including the bindings are working fine. Now I have found out that on this version of gdal it is not possible to use TILED=YES on GeoTIFFS as the version is too old.

I thus installed Python 3.7.8 64bit with GDAL 3.3.3. The problem is now though, that I have to set the environment variables GDAL_DATA and GDAL_DRIVER_PATH again.

Can I randomly name these variable names (e.g. GDAL_DATA_PY37) or do I have to register them somehow ?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to set the `PATH`, `GDAL_DATA`, `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` again

You can use the following recipe. For this, you need to paste in a file with a name like `gdal_37.bat`. Each time you need some GDAL utility with specific version, run the bat before and it should work

```
PATH=C:\gdal\bin\;%PATH%
GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins
```

`C:\gdal\bin\` (in `PATH`) should be replaced by path directory from your specific install where utilities like `ogrinfo.exe` are located

`C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal` (in `GDAL_DATA`) should be replaced with the path directory where `epsg.wkt` or `gt_datum.csv` files reside.

`C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins` should be replace with path where files like `gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll` are.

If you use something like Conda to install GDAL, you do not need to care about these annoying environment variables as it manages them for you behind the scenes.